# Correlation between RTT and geographical distance

Tags: networking

Cany one explain what sort of correlation exists positive or negative between RTT and geographical distance?. How is it calculated

Comment: Can someone tell me if I cut the red wire or the blue wire?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, research has shown there is a positive correlation between RTT and geographical distance. I suggest you read [correlation between delay and distance](http://www.usenix.org/events/usenix02/full_papers/subramanian/subramanian_html/node21.html).

Answer (score 2):

There is a positive correlation between distance and RTT. There are a number of reasons for this. For example, an increased hop count. The packets have to through more routers, at each router there may be a delay, tshethe more routers, the longer the RTT.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. The farther the distance the larger the RTT.